# azure data explorer for activity logging

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, audit-logging

We are looking to provide a historic activity log on objects in our system(similar to jira's history tab). We are looking at Azure Data Explorer as a potential tool for addressing this usecase.

sample queries we need to answer:
give me all objects that have changed in the last 30 days.
give me all objects that have changed in the last 30 days that have value of key1 set to value1.
give me all the objects that userA changed in the last year.

The amount of data(objects) we have is huge(could be tens of millions), but the activity itself is not, and will not be in a streaming format for sure. Is this a right usecase for using Azure Data Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Azure Data Explorer (Kusto) is the ideal cloud service for this functionality. You can learn more about the service by watching the recent [online event](https://youtu.be/4wcfT7hN1Vw) and using the [quick starts in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/).

Comment: we noticed this doesn't support pagination, and we have to do some special logic to be able to do pagination, (something like store ids and handle pagination on the client end),